# Beginner C++ calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm relatively new to programming, but am really enjoying it. I have taken a couple of classes but mostly code for fun (for now). I decided to make a program implementing some basic functions, switch statements, and user input. Please leave any feedback on how to make this program better.

I understand that I am not actually using the defined functions (add, subtract, etc.), but I put them in there with the intent of using them, I just don't know how.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add (int x, int y){
return x+y;
};

int divide (int x, int y){
return x/y;
}

int multiply (int x, int y){
return x*y;
}

int subtract (int x, int y){
return x-y;
}


int main(){

int n1;
int n2;
int user14 = 0;

SomeLine:
cout << "Enter your 2 numbers: "<< endl;
cin >> n1;
cin >> n2;


cout << "Ok, now what do you want to do with those numbers? "<< endl;

cout << "1) Add: " << endl;
cout << "2) Divide: "<<endl;
cout << "3) Multiply: "<< endl;
cout << "4) Subtration: "<< endl;

cin >> user14;

switch (user14)
{
    case 1:
    cout << n1+n2 << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
    cout << n1/n2 << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
    cout << n1*n2<< endl;
        break;
    case 4:
    cout << n1-n2 << endl;
        break;

}

char userchoice;
cout << "Would you like to perform any other operations? y/n "<< endl;

cin >> userchoice;

if (userchoice=='y'){
    goto SomeLine;
}
else if(userchoice=='n'){
    goto Exit;
}

Exit:
return 0;

};
```

Comment: `x/y;` should make sure that `y` is not `0`.  Instead of using `goto`, a `do.. while` loop is better

Comment: Your program doesn't call the functions named `multiply`, `divide`, `add` and `subtract`. :)

Comment: Minor thing: If the code in the question doesn't look like (i.e. isn't indented the same as) your actual code, instead of manually indenting every line, try pasting the block in, selecting the entire block, and hitting Ctrl+K (Cmd+K on Mac).

Answer (score 30):

Welcome! Here is some feedback, in no particular order.

### Avoid `using namespace std`

This advice is [often repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6789498) for good reason. See also: code guidelines [SF.6](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-348). It's useful when you're learning the C++ standard library to know what belongs in the standard library and what doesn't.

```
cout << "Enter your 2 numbers: "<< endl;
```

Becomes

```
std::cout << "Enter your 2 numbers: "<< std::endl;
```

### Consistent spacing

Maybe this is caused by the formatting on Stack Exchange. There are many online style guides, I would choose one that is most readable to you and your peers and stick with it throughout the source code.

```
int add (int x, int y){
return x+y;
};
```

Becomes

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
};
```

### Semicolons

Functions don't need semicolons at the end (`main` & `add`). This is only used for [function prototypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype).

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
};
```

Becomes

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

### Avoid `std::endl`

Unless you need to flush the stream, using `std::endl` can be replaced with a newline character.

```
std::cout << "Enter your 2 numbers: "<< std::endl;
```

Becomes

```
std::cout << "Enter your 2 numbers:\n";
```

### Combine multiple `std::cout` and `std::cin` calls.

This is just my preference. It reduces the amount of code I have to write.

```
std::cin >> n1;
std::cin >> n2;
```

Becomes

```
std::cin >> n1 >> n2;
```

And

```
std::cout << "1) Add: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "2) Divide: "<< std::endl;
std::cout << "3) Multiply: "<< std::endl;
std::cout << "4) Subtration: "<< std::endl;
```

Becomes

```
std::cout << "1) Add:\n2) Divide:\n3) Multiply:\n4) Subtration:\n";
```

In the above example, there are many other ways to do it. For example, you can use multi-line strings, adding the strings, and so on.

### Make use of your functions

You define the `add`, `divide`, `multiply` and `subtract` functions, but you don't call them. Here is how you would do that:

```
std::cout << n1 + n2 << '\n';
```

Becomes

```
std::cout << add(n1, n2) << '\n';
```

It's as simple as that!

In complex applications, splitting things into functions makes the code easier to work with. For example, say you wanted the "add" operation to have saturating arithmetic (doesn't overflow). It's easier to add that logic to a separate function rather than inserting it into a long block of code.

Or, if you want to handle a division-by-zero case.

### Don't use `goto`

While `goto` is useful in a few cases, it's not particularly useful here. Instead you can use a do-while loop.

```
SomeLine:

// code

if (userchoice == 'y'){
    goto SomeLine;
}
else if(userchoice == 'n'){
    goto Exit;
}

Exit:
return 0;
```

Becomes

```
do {
     // code
} while (userchoice == 'y');

return 0;
```

### Variable naming

The variables `x` and `y` are used in the function signatures. You can also use those names in `main`. I'd prefer that over `n1` and `n2`. Likewise, `user14` is vague (do we change it to `user15` if we include another operation?). Something like `operation` or `op` isn't vague. `userchoice` is a bit long, `exit` is shorter and clearly shows its purpose.

### `const`

Make use of the `const` keyword where it makes sense. For example, in `add`, we intend for the `x` and `y` variables to never themselves be modified. So we can declare them as `const`, and the compiler will give us an error if we accidentally change their values.

This isn't particularly useful anything other than readability here, but can be useful if you get into more advanced topics, such as `const` references.

The functions `add`, `divide`, `multiply`, and `subtract` can be [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr). The compiler may already evaluate these at compile time, but using `constexpr` marks them as such (broadly speaking).

### Move variables to the lowest scope

Now that we've gotten rid of the `goto`s, we can move `x`, `y`, and `op` to a lower scope. They can also all be declared on the same line.

### Consider edge cases

The following are a few example cases where you may wish to add extra handling -- or leave as it currently is.

- What if the user enters a letter where you're expecting an integer?
- What if the user enters an operation number outside of the range?
- What about possible signed integer overflow (undefined behavior)?
- What about division-by-zero?
- What if the input stream is no longer valid after user input?
- ...

### Conclusion

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int add(const int x, const int y) {
    return x + y;
}

constexpr int divide(const int x, const int y) {
    return x / y;
}

constexpr int multiply(const int x, const int y) {
    return x * y;
}

constexpr int subtract(const int x, const int y) {
    return x - y;
}


int main() {
    char exit;

    do {
        int x, y, op;

        std::cout << "Enter your 2 numbers:\n";

        std::cin >> x >> y;

        std::cout << "Ok, now what do you want to do with those numbers?\n";
        std::cout << "1) Add:\n2) Divide:\n3) Multiply:\n4) Subtration:\n";

        std::cin >> op;

        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << add(x, y) << '\n';
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << divide(x, y) << '\n';
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << multiply(x, y) << '\n';
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << subtract(x, y) << '\n';
                break;
        }

        std::cout << "Would you like to perform any other operations? y/n\n";

        std::cin >> exit;
    } while (exit == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully this has been helpful. I hope you continue to enjoy programming as much as we all do!

Comment: Wow! Such great feedback. The indenting was due to formatting, like you said. I will get in the habit of avoiding using namespace std. I’ve taken 3 coding classes (c++ 1 and 2, and data structures) and all my instructors have used it. Poor practice I suppose. I am familiar with do while loops and am not entirely sure why I chose otherwise. Getting in the habit of declaring variables in single lines seems to be very effective as well. I look forward to posting more of my programs as I progress and hopefully return as much useful feedback as I have. Thank you!

Comment: Minor nit: `add()` is a **function**, not a "method" (by which I assume you mean a *member function*, since C++ doesn't define the term).

Comment: Oh, and even after recommending some error checking, your final version still neglects to ever check the state of `std::cin` after the formatted input operations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your point about avoiding `std::endl` and instead using `\n`? Is it just to type less or there are important differences to be taken in account? Thanks

Comment: It's not a header file, so your using namespace std guideline does not apply. I'd tend to go the other way on multiple calls to std::cout << as merging them onto one line is harder to maintain and harder to read and spot the spelling error. Putting constexpr on a function that is only used in one file to process user input is probably YAGNI.

Comment: @TobySpeight Updated method->function. I've been doing too much Java recently. Added an edge case of checking `std::cin`. Thanks! @PeteKirkham I had linked to the wrong guidelines section. I updated the link. For chaining `std::cout` calls that's ultimately up to preference--I don't find it hard to read, but I see how others could. `constexpr` isn't helpful here, I more just wanted to bring it up to introduce OP to the topic.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Both. [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) does more than just print a newline, it also [flushes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) the stream. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/6789498).

Comment: I still see `std::cin >> x >> y` and `std::cin >> op` and `std::cin >> exit` in the "Conclusion" code without any `if (std::cin)`.  Where did you add the test?

Comment: @TobySpeight added a line in the "consider edge cases" section. If I have time tonight I may be able to come back & update the code itself.

Comment: You do need to flush the stream if prompting the user for input.  `std::endl` is correct.  If the stream isn't line-buffered or unbuffered, then the prompt does not appear.

Comment: @PeteKirkham It's still going to bite you in the ass if you get used to doing it. Dive into ODR and ADL stuff -- it's "fun". It's not just about _not_ `using namespace std`, but always qualifying calls.

Comment: @esote Why not just get rid of the unused functions entirely, instead of using them? Or, if you really _want_ to use them, you could always do something with function pointers. I mean, you probably shouldn't, but it'd be a neat trick.

Comment: @Kaz `std::cin` is tied to `std::cout`, so the flushing happens automatically. See [`std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie)

Answer (score 9):

One item missing from the other replies is that you should avoid mixing output and computations.

Instead of

```
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << add(x, y) << '\n';
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << divide(x, y) << '\n';
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << multiply(x, y) << '\n';
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << subtract(x, y) << '\n';
            break;
    }
```

Use:

```
    int res;
    switch (op) {
        case 1:
            res = add(x, y);
            break;
        case 2:
            res = divide(x, y);
            break;
        case 3:
            res = multiply(x, y);
            break;
        case 4:
            res = divide(x, y);
            break;
    }
    std::cout << res << '\n';
```

Or turn this into a separate function:

```
   int computation(int op, int x, y) {
    switch (op) {
        case 1:
            return add(x, y);
        case 2:
            return divide(x, y);
        case 3:
            return multiply(x, y);
        case 4:
            return divide(x, y);
     }
   }
   ...
   int res=computation(op, x, y);
```

There are two reasons:

- Easier to debug.
- Easier to change the formatting of the output in a common way.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome on Code Review!

---

#### Don't use `using namespace std;`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/5416291) that can cause a lot of problems that are easy to avoid, most people are used to the prefix, and three letters aren't that hard to type.

- Although it's "safe" to use it in some place (e.g. implementation files), as long as you aren't familiar with the features of c ++, [try to avoid it](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#using-namespace-std).
- It led to a world of name collisions. (best case)
- It's source of silent errors and weird bugs. (worst case)
- If typing `std::` is so tedious for you, try to import only *truncated namespaces*. ( e.g. individual identifiers like `using std::string;` or nested names like `using namespace std::literals`).
- If importing nested namespaces still too awful for you, try to do it [inside a restricted scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) (e.g. a functions) and not in global scope.

---

#### Ensure validity of parameters

In your `add()`,  `substract()`,  `multiply()` and `divide()` function, you don't check the validity of given inputs. You could surely use assertions to ensure that the operation don't lead to integer overflow/underflow or division by zero.

You *could* use assertions to check preconditions, postconditions and invariants. It make your code more explicit and you avoid possibly broke you code when modifying.

- [How to use assertions in C](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/~johnr/tutorials/assertions.html) (for C, but still applicable here)
- [How and When to Use C's assert() Macro](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Use-Assert-Macro) (same, also valid)
- [Why should I use asserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081409/why-should-i-use-asserts)

---

#### Inputs / Outputs

- When you read values from user input, [consider it ill-formed](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#slio2-when-reading-always-consider-ill-formed-input), so [check for validity](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#istream-and-ignore) and sanitize input. Never trust user, They all try to broke your program.
- Using `std::endl` sending a `'\n'` and then flushes the output buffer. So `std::endl` is more expensive in performance. So, use '\n' `'\n'` and then, if you want to manually flush the stream, explicitly call [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush).

---

#### Use your functions

If you don't know how to use your function, I think you really have to learn to basics. Their are a lot of resources on the net. Once you get basics, dive into the [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq) and the [C++ Core Guideline](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html) to get some good practices.

Also, it's Christmas soon, a good opportunity to ask for [a good book about C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

---

#### Misc

- When it's possible, try to [avoid using `goto`](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#Res-goto).
- [Don't `return 0` from `main()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402853/must-the-int-main-function-return-a-value-in-all-compilers).
- You should also fix indentation.

Comment: `namespace std::string;` is clearly an error, since `std::string` names a class, not a namespace.

Comment: `return 0;` is not _necessary_ in `main` but I can't see any reason to recommend against doing it. What is you reason for suggesting this?

Comment: @TobySpeight thx for pointing out this typo.

Comment: So "truncated namespaces" is a term for "individual identifiers", then?  I'd not seen that phrase before; where is it defined?

Comment: Probably a language abuse, as you already know, I never learned English ;) But yeah, it stand for individual identifiers. But also, nested namespace (e.g. using `namespace std::literals`). I don't know how to explain it clearly

Comment: You should **not** use assertions to validate user input. Assertions are intended to catch programming errors. What happens if you use the program without assertions enabled and your user inputs some invalid values? (Also triggering assertions make for an awful user experience, but let's ignore that for a second). You can use assertions to make sure that your input validation code is correct if you want though. (In this case writing the correct assertions will be surprisingly tricky though, that's probably something for a later day)

Comment: @JackAidley By not using a `return 0` is a convention that indicates that the application can never fail. Thus as a developer I don't need to look for the situations where the code will return an error. The convention says if your code can return an error (i.e. there are returns other than 0 elsewhere) then you should add the `return 0` at the end. So if you see `return 0` at the end you start looking for the error conditions. If you see no `return 0` then you don't need to look for error situations the app is so simple it always just exits normally.

Answer (score 2):

**Default case!**

In addition to the other excellent answers, you could add a default case to your switch statement! This is the case that is called when something other than the expected input is received.

In your example, it would end up looking something like this:

```
switch (user14)
{
    case 1: 
        Add(n1, n2);
        break;
    case 2:
        Subtract(n1, n2);
        break;
    case 3:
        Multiply(n1, n2);
        break;
    case 4:
        Divide(n1, n2);
        break;
    Default:
        cout << "Invalid operation\n";
        break;
}
```

In the above code, a 1, 2, 3, or 4 will perform the expected corresponding action, as in your original code. But in your original code, any other numerical input will just exit the switch statement and move on to the next thing, without telling the user that no action was taken. In the example above, it will instead tell the user why no action is being taken.

It's a useful way to let the user know that their input was invalid, but it can also be used to automatically take an action if none of the cases are matched. If that is confusing, you can think of default like the final "else" at the end of a series of "if/else if" statements.

On the other hand, if there's no need for user feedback and there's no "default" action that you want to happen normally, then there's no need to make a default case.

Another change I might suggest is for user14, I would personally use a **char** instead of an **int**. This will stop the program from crashing if the user inputs something other than an integer. But then, if you know that the input will only ever be an integer, then there's really no need to take that precaution!

Happy coding!